# Unable to see console errors on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, netbeans, glassfish

I created a HTML page and when I open the page by simply clicking on it everything works fine. But when I open the page from Glassfish server from my Netbeans I cannot see the background image of the web page. Any ideas why this is happening?

The background image is displayed from the CSS using below code,

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Another question is if I open the webpage by just clicking on it I'm able to see the errors and warnings in the console but when I open the webpage from my Netbeans using Glassfish server I can't see any console errors.

Thanks in advance.

**PS:** The size of the image is 1.21 MB

Answer (score 0):

This is the most weirdest reason that I'm seeing. I found that my image name is, `header.JPG` and I was using `header.jpg`(jpg in lowercase). I thought that HTML/CSS is case-insensitive. The most unusual thing is the browser used when I'm directly clicking on the web page and when I'm using Netbeans is same but yet I face the problem so that's weird.

Comment: As far as I know, this is caused by the fact that it's a path. As the HTTP protocol is case sensitive, and I expect the CSS property will issue an HTTP request, this hits you.
Some browsers tend to handle the case sensitivity better than others, so this might be the reason for the inconsistent behavior.